# How to make predictions using an LDA (Linear discriminant analysis) model in R

Tags: r, linear-discriminant

as the title suggests I am trying to make predictions using an LDA model in R. I have two sets of data that I'm working with: the first set is a series of entries associated with 16 predictor variables and 1 outcome variable (the outcome variable are "groups" that each entry belongs to that I've assigned myself), the second set of data also consists of entries associated with the same 16 predictor variables, but with no outcome variable. What I would like to do is predict the group membership of the entries in the second set of data.

So far I've successfully managed to create an LDA model by separating the first dataset into a "training set" and a "test set". However, now that I have the model I don't know how I would go about predicting the group membership of the entries in my second data set.

Thanks for the help! Please let me know if any more information is required, this is my first post on stack overflow so I am still learning the ropes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Short example based on [An introduction to Statistical learning, chapter 4](https://hastie.su.domains/ISLR2/ISLRv2_website.pdf). Say you have fitted a model `lda_model` on a `training_data` set, with dependent variable `Group` which you aim to predict, and predictors `Predictor1` and `Predictor2`

```
library(MASS)
lda_model <- lda(Group∼ Predictor1 + Predictor2, data = training_set)
```

You can then make predictions with the `lda_model` using the `predict` function on the `testing_set`

```
lda_predictions <- predict(lda_model, testing_set)
```

`lda_predictions` then holds the posterior probabilities in `$posterior` that the observation is part of `Group` j.

You could then apply a threshold of for instance (but not limiting to) 50% probability. E.g.

```
sum(lda_model$posterior[, 7] >= .5)
```

returns the number of observations for which the probabilty that the observation is part of `Group` 7 is larger than 50%

Comment: Thanks for the answer, definitely super helpful! Will give it a go, and hopefully it'll work.